# Why does my .gitlab-ci.yml keep failing on yarn test with error "/bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found"?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, node-modules, yarnpkg

Here I have a simple react app created with npx create-react-app.

The pipeline successfully extracts the cache but fails on `yarn test --watchAll=false` with error "/bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found".

How do I fix this?.

The react app is located in a src/client directory hence the before_script to cd in the correct directory as seen in the yml file below.

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:latest

default:
  before_script:
    - cd src/client

stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

build_react:
  stage: build
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - build

test_react:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pwd
    - yarn test --watchAll=false
```

Comment: Does GitLab CI retain context between stages? You may have to install again in the test stage.

Comment: Through the use of cache the node_modules are shared between stages. I tried setting up a react app in another project with everything at the root directory so then in the .gitlab-ci.yml i do not need to cd into different directories and it works perfectly, so i think the thing that causes problems is the changing of directories, no idea why. As a workaround i'm currently doing everything in one stage until i figure out a solution.

Comment: A suggestion for debugging: in test_react job, list "src/client" to see if it's indeed there. If not there, you have to explicitly pass it to test stage then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifacts are downloaded and extracted before any scripts are run, so it'll be extracted to`{project_root}/`, then your default before_script will run. You should be able to reference the build directory by `../../build`, or move it to `src/client` in your `test_react` job.